# I want to run my script as different user automatically when system start or reboot

Tags: linux, cron, users

I have created new user as newUser using `sudo adduser newUser sudo` i also set a password for it using `sudo passwd newUser` now what i want is to run a script from this newUser just say i created a script to create a new folder using `mkdir` and also i want to be get executed automatically when system get started or get rebooted so i used `@reboot` feature in `crontab`. So i want this script to get executed from newUser, and also i did set a password for root user too using `sudo passwd root` and by default this script is getting executed by root and i want it to get executed as newUser

Thanks.

Comment: ... and what is your question/problem?

Comment: well this script is getting executed by root i don't want it, i want to run it from newUser.

Answer (score 2):

A cron job will be executed as the user who owns the crontab.

This means that you should add the `@reboot` job to the crontab of `newUser`.

You may do this in two ways:

1. As root, run `crontab -u newUser -e` to add the job's schedule to the crontab of `newUser`, or
2. Log in as `newUser` and run `crontab -e` to add the schedule.

As your ordinary day-to-day user, you may do the first through

```
sudo crontab -u newUser -e
```

or the second through

```
sudo -u newUser crontab -e
```

(assuming your ordinary user is allowed to use `sudo -u newUser`).

Comment: Ok got it, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The first two ways I can think of are:

1] Just use `sudo`, it is made to literally run a program as another user. Run the line below as root for example, where 'root' runs a program as if it was the user 'newUser'`

```
root@foo $> sudo -u newUser whoami 
=> newUser
```

Then, remember to read `man sudo`.

2] There may be differences in distributions, but in the system I use each user has his own crontab. So, if you want the user `newUser` to run something at boot.

```
newUser@foo $> crontab -e
```

and you insert your `@reboot` line there.

Comment: i added it in newUser crontab -e `@reboot /usr/local/bin/myScript.sh` but its not creating a folder why? also i removed it from root corntab -e

Comment: @AyushVerma We can't answer that because we don't know what your script is doing. If you want help with that you should probably ask a new question (as it's more or less a separate question from how to manage the actual cron schedule).

Comment: take into account that usally cron sends error messages to the mailbox of the user who runs it. So you should definitely check there for the error messages.